# Doctrine adds extra queries during hydration causing n+1 problem with "normal" one to one and self-referenced relations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, select-n-plus-1

`News` are related to each other using one-to-many self-referencing approach (one news is parent and can have many children). What's more each `News` has got normal (non self-referenced) one to one relation with `Event` and `Gallery` . When I run simple DQL:

```sql
SELECT n FROM App\Entity\News n WHERE n.parent = :id
```

and then hydrate results by `getResults` method with default `HYDRATION_OBJECT` value set, extra queries are made somewhere inside `getResults` method.

```
SELECT t0.* FROM event t0 WHERE t0.news_id = 2 AND ((t0.deleted_at IS NULL));
SELECT t0.* FROM gallery t0 WHERE t0.news_id = 2 AND ((t0.deleted_at IS NULL));
SELECT t0.* FROM event t0 WHERE t0.news_id = 1 AND ((t0.deleted_at IS NULL));
SELECT t0.* FROM gallery t0 WHERE t0.news_id = 1 AND ((t0.deleted_at IS NULL));
```

Where `news_id = 1` and `news_id = 2` are children of news selected by first query.

`News` has got also not self-referenced one to many relations (I ignored them here), but hydration make no extra queries about them. The problem occurs only when there is `parent` relation involved in `where` statement.

**How to reproduce**

```
// news Entity
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\NewsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="news_slug_deleted", columns={"slug","deleted_at"})})
 */
class News {
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128)
     */
    private $slug;
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Gallery", mappedBy="news", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     *
     * @var Gallery
     */
    private $gallery;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", mappedBy="news", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     *
     * @var Event
     */
    private $event;
    /**
     * One News has Many News.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * Many News have One News.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="News", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable()
 */
class Event
{
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\News", inversedBy="event", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $news;
```

`Gallery` entity is simmilar to `Event` so I ignored it here.

```
// News controller

public function index(NewsRepository $newsRepository, $slug)
{
        $news = $newsRepository->findOneBy(['slug' => $slug]);
        $newsRepository->getConnectedNews($news->getId());
}
```

```
// news repository

class NewsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, News::class);
    }
    public function getConnectedNews($newsId) {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')->andWhere('n.parent = :id')->setParameter('id', $newsId);
        return $query->getQuery()->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
    }
}
```

Hydration of `news` which has got 20 children ends up with: 20 * 2 + 1 (n*r+1) queries, where:

- (n) 20 is the number of children
- (r) 2 is the number of one to one relations
- 1 is the basic query

I want to prevent that extra queries to one to one relations made by Doctrine. Is it Doctrine bug or unwanted behaviour or I made a mistake somewhere?

All in all I want to just get all self-referenced children without one-to-one relations as I didn't ask to retrieve them so it should use just one query to get all children `news` without making additional queries for each retrieved 'news' object and each it's one to one relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple inverse OneToOne relationships in that entity.

Inverse OneToOne relationships cannot be lazy-loaded by Doctrine, and can easily become a performance problem.

If you *really* need to have those relationships mapped on the *inverse* side (and not only on the owning side) make sure to make the appropriate joins explicitly, or mark those associations as `FETCH=EAGER` so that Doctrine makes the joins for you.

E.g. a query that would avoid the dreaded "n+1" problem would be:

```
SELECT n, g, e
    FROM App\Entity\News n
    LEFT JOIN n.gallery g
    LEFT JOIN n.event e
WHERE n.parent = :id
```

You can read more about the N+1 problem in Doctrine [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4389) or [here](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/5-doctrine-orm-performance-traps-you-should-avoid).

Comment: But why does Doctrine even try to load that one to one relations? If I execute query without self-referencing relation everything is ok for example:
`SELECT n FROM App\Entity\News n WHERE n.id = :id` I get single query without one to one relations, which is correct. 
If I use `fetch=eager` it solves that problem by joining 2 others relations like in your example, but it will cause another problems in another case. Basically I want Doctrine to ignore that relation when in where statement there is self-referenced relation just like it does in other queries.

Comment: "Inverse OneToOne relationships cannot be lazy-loaded by Doctrine" - I haven't noticed any problems with that relations in any of my queries so far. The problem occured when I added that self-referenced parent-child relation to `news` entity and only when I added `parent` field to `where` statement.

Comment: The only problem with inverse onetoone relationships is that they can't be lazy loaded, so they trigger additional queries **unless** you join explicitly or use `FETCH=EAGER`. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/4389) or [here](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/5-doctrine-orm-performance-traps-you-should-avoid), for example. If you apply what I mention in the answer, you won't get this additional queries.

Comment: Thank you for that links and clarification. There is nice workaround to use fake one to many relationship which pretends to be one to one and can be lazy loaded.
I corrected your answer because in select you have to provide all entities to retrieve (gallery and event). Only joining without that wouldn't work.
I have already tried the `fetch=eager` solution before but it generates much more queries in another test case. It turned out that there was another problem with another many to many relation. This is why I rejected both of your solutions at first.
All in all everything it's clear.